# Error when declaring and defining arrays in vbscript

Tags: arrays, vbscript

```
Sub A() 
  Dim arr(4)
  arr = Array(&H0, &H2, &H4, &H6, &H8)
  Wscript.echo arr(1)
End Sub
```

The above vbs function gives and error. However when I remove the declaration, the code is working fine.

```
Sub A() 
  arr = Array(&H0, &H2, &H4, &H6, &H8)
  Wscript.echo arr(1)
End Sub
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: This is a classic issue that programmers run into. @Ekkehard.Horner The solution below is what I would recommend. Always use OPTION EXPLICIT to enforce good programming habits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dim arr(4)` declares/dims **and** initializes a **fixed** (optimized, non-resizeable) array of 5 (empty) elements. `arr = Array(...)` tries to re-assign/overwrite this variable with a **dynamic** (re-sizable) array. That is not allowed.

Use `Option Explicit` and

```
Dim arr ' just a variant; make known the name
arr = Array(...) ' replace with dynamic array
```